# Django: DatabaseError: near "��...��1": syntax error

Tags: python, django, sqlite, utf-8, python-unicode

The code:

```
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> objects = serializers.deserialize('xml', fixturestr.encode('utf8'))
>>> o = next(objects)
>>> o
<DeserializedObject: countries.Country(pk=AF)>
>>> type(o)
<class 'django.core.serializers.base.DeserializedObject'>
>>> dir(o)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'm2m_data', 'object', 'save']
>>> o.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 524, in save_base
    manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val).exists())):
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 562, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 441, in has_results
    return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DatabaseError: near "����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������1": syntax error
```

The query and params:

```
(Pdb) query
u'SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "country" WHERE "country"."iso" = ?  LIMIT 1'
(Pdb) params
(u'AF',)
```

To be honest I'm stumped - I don't even know where to go with this one. The query shouldn't even be as long as the horror presented. The error message doesn't decode as utf-8, either.

The underlying task is to read in an xml fixture and push it to the database. Unfortunately, the standard `loaddata` command can't cope with non-ascii characters in utf-8 xml (see my other recent questions if you're interested). For that reason, I'm trying to do what `loaddata` does, but manually, so that I can pass the deserializer utf-8 encoded bytes.

Running python 2.7.5 with django 1.4 on linux.

I will be grateful for a way to avoid this problem entirely, or any hints on how to solve or even further diagnose it.

Update: This is the result of trying the query manually:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite3.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute(u'SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "country" WHERE "country"."iso" = ?  LIMIT 1', (u'AF',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
OperationalError: near "����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������1": syntax error
>>> c.execute(u'SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "country" WHERE "country"."iso" = AF  LIMIT 1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
OperationalError: near "����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������": syntax error
>>> c.execute(u'SELECT * from "country" WHERE "country"."iso" = AF  LIMIT 1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
OperationalError: near "��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������1����": syntax error
>>> c.execute(u'SELECT * from "country"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
OperationalError: near "������������������������������������": syntax error
>>> c.execute('SELECT * from "country"')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x4123f10>
>>>
```

My terminal is set to use utf-8. It's not clear why passing a unicode object is going so horribly wrong.

Update 2: This is the version info for sqlite:

```
>>> sqlite3.version_info
(2, 6, 0)
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
(3, 7, 11)
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.11'
>>> sqlite3.x
'11'
>>>
```

update 3: The same error occurs for every table in the database, if attempting to use unicode strings.

update 4: The same error affects fresh databases. Here's the result of running [the example code from the python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), then trying to do a unicode query:

```
>>> conn.close()
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> 
>>> # Create table
>>> c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
...              (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x43e9180>
>>> 
>>> # Insert a row of data
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x43e9180>
>>> 
>>> # Save (commit) the changes
>>> conn.commit()
>>> c.execute(u'SELECT * FROM "stocks"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
OperationalError: near "����������������������������": syntax error
>>>
```

Update 5: The package which provides the sqlite libraries is `sqlite-3.7.11-3.fc17.x86_64`.

Comment: Does it happen all the time or just for a few `fixturestr`?

Comment: @btoueg I only have one fixture.

Comment: Does the same query function correctly from the command line sqlite3 client?

Comment: @AustinPhillips Yes. In fact, it works fine from python if the query is passed as a bytestring (see the update for that). However, given that the django save code uses unicode, I can't rewrite that to encode all queries appropriately first.

Comment: BTW, this is the underlying cause of the exception shown in your "django loaddata insists on reading xml fixture as ascii" question. Django is not actually having trouble reading your UTF-8 XML, but is having trouble generating the error message that it tries to use to wrap this `DatabaseError`. It tries to string interpolate that same weird mix of characters into an error message, and fails. If you figure out why this happens, you won't actually need a custom load command.

Comment: As for what's going wrong...that is deeply weird. Do queries on other tables, if any, show the same error? Is there data in the database that might have come from another source? I would probably try creating a new empty sqlite database, letting syncdb create the tables, and trying the import there. At least that would help narrow down whether or not there's something off about your existing db.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Right, that at least sounds like a direction to search in.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Every table I've checked seems affected by the same problem.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper It turns out fresh databases are affected by the same issue. Apart from eliminating the database contents as the problem, I'm really not sure what's causing this.

Comment: Odd.  Are you using Python's version of sqlite3?  What does `python -c 'import sqlite3; print sqlite3.__file__'` return?

Comment: @AustinPhillips Thanks - I was actually wondering how to check this. The result is `/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.pyc`. I'm going to hunt around and make sure I don't have two different versions of python (which due to an upgrade snafu is a possibility).

Comment: FWIW I get the same path on a Debian system.  The .so sqlite shared object being used `python -c 'import _sqlite3; print _sqlite3.__file__'` is `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so`.

Comment: @AustinPhillips Thanks for your help. I'm fairly certain it was an unholy mixture of versions that did this to me.

Answer (score 0):

This was almost certainly caused by my having two different versions of python. After I cleared out the existing python, and reinstalled from source, everything works as it should.

For those who want to recompile from source:

1. Redhat compiles with UCS-4 enabled, as opposed to the default UCS-2. You probably want to configure with something like `./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-unicode=ucs4`.
2. Python has a lot of dependencies. The package manager commands here are probably the easiest way to figure out what you're missing: http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html‎.
3. Remember if you're using a virtualenv that your environment is likely not picking up changes in your global python.